# taking MQTT messages from AWS IOT core to website/webapp

Tags: amazon-web-services, nvidia

I have successfully connected my jetson nano to my AWS account following this guide:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-iot-core-integration-with-nvidia-deepstream

according to this guide, I can see MQTT messages from deepstream test-app 4 and 5 on my AWS test.

I now want to take these MQTT messages to preferably an website/webapp. Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

I am sorry I am a novice about these things and it is absolutely possible I have missed some easy points somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the example you provided, but the overall best way to do this is to utilize [WebSockets](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-websockets/), which [AWS IOT supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html). You can use an API to do most of the work for you, the best one is the [Paho-MQTT API for Javascript](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) (also comes in python and PHP flavors).

Also just a helpful note, AWS IOT was designed to support extremely complex and demanding IoT networks on a commercial scale. It's incredibly robust but fairly complicated to use if you are just testing/developing. A well-secured small server with the Mosquitto broker on it is much easier to begin learning things with. You will spend lots of time learning how AWS does things and very little time learning about MQTT!

[Try this tutorial](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) out and learn about WebSockets, then try the API.